# Why can't I extract the array values using Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a 4 x 6 element string array, and I need to extract the elements, but nothing I have tried works.  I am a rank novice at Python, and I must admit I don't understand Numpy at all.

```py
CV = np.genfromtxt("/usr/lib/cgi-bin/Data/ClassFile.csv",delimiter=",") # Get setup parameters
ClassValues = CV.astype(str)
```

The array is:

```
F,C,,,,
12 hr,24 hr,,,,
inHg,mmHg,,,,
Master,Client,Outside,Remote,Vent,Relay
```

but all I get is

```
nan nan nan nan nan nan
nan nan nan nan nan nan
nan nan nan nan nan nan
nan nan nan nan nan nan
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.genfromtxt` takes a `dtype` argument to cast the input to, which by default is `float`. Call it with `dtype=str` and you'll be fine.

Comment: That did it!  Thanks.

Comment: @lrhorer If the answer helped you, please mark it as accepted. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).